# Is there global query SORTERS like query FILTERS in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

Is there something like IHaveOrder interface and all entities (classes) that implement it ordered by default when getall()

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There are global query filters, but no 'global query sorters'. :) But if you use any sort of abstraction (e.g. repository over DbContext, or simply just exposing `IQueryable` instead of `DbSet`), it's trivial to define a base query that includes the sorting you wish to be the default. Which you can do programmatically, by checking if the entity class implements an interface. If you have a concrete requirement for that, you could mention it, and then it could be part of the answer.

Comment: I can see why global filters make sense, eg soft delete.. but isn't sorting more a front end concern?

Comment: I was hoping there is a clean and better way like global query filters.
Thanks @Leaky for suggestions.

Comment: If it will make code easier and cleaner why not @CaiusJard

Comment: Cleaner is rather subjective, but I'm not sure it's sensible from a performance perspective to sort *everything*..

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that in your DBContext :

```
public  class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
   public IQueryable<MyEntity> MyOrderedEntities => MyEntities.OrderBy(...)
}
```